# Can't use pgRouting functions in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.4, pgrouting

I have 3 pgRouting sql files,

- routing_core
- routing_core_wrappers
- routing_topology

And I run the code in the first one in PostgreSQL 9.2, I got this error,

[image]

**PS. although there are already pgRouting functions in extensions of 9.2, I still can't run the following code,**

```
ALTER TABLE tc_2000_w_area ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE tc_2000_w_area ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT assign_vertex_id('tc_2000_w_area', 0.0001, 'the_geom', 'gid')
```

**got the error,**

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Heinz/Desktop/python_test/any_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur.execute(query)
ProgrammingError: 錯誤:  函式 assign_vertex_id(unknown, numeric, unknown, unknown) 不存在
LINE 4:     SELECT assign_vertex_id('tc_2000_w_area', 0.0001, 'the_g...
                   ^
HINT:  沒有符合指定之名稱和參數型別的函式。您可能需要加入明確型別轉換。
```

**So I think to run the above 3 sql files first.**

But I can run all 3 sql files in PostgreSQL 8.4

I am working with PostgreSQL 9.2, PostgreSQL 8.4 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**UPDATE#1**

I run the code below, but shows error message,

```
create extension pgrouting;
```

---

```
錯誤:  擴充功能 "pgrouting" 已存在

********** 錯誤 **********

錯誤: 擴充功能 "pgrouting" 已存在
SQL 狀態: 42710
```

the error message means the pgRouting extension already exists, but if I directly use the code in my original post, got the same error as I posted.

Comment: Did you `CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;` in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install postgis before pgrouting.

```
create extension postgis;

create extension pgrouting;
```

Then you should be able to use it.